# Branch and Bound approach for solving Longest Common Subsequence(LCS).

Tags: algorithm, lcs, branch-and-bound

Is there a way to solve longest common subsequence([LCS](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html)) problem using branch and bound technique. I understand branch and bound but I am not able to apply the technique to solve LCS. Just wanted forum opinion to point in right direction to find the solution.

Comment: In order to apply B&B to a maximisation problem like this one, you need to somehow generate partial solutions that give *upper* bounds on the solution size (length of the common subsequence).  The usual recursive procedure that would generate all common subsequences will produce sequences of *increasing* length as you go deeper in the search tree -- that is, that give *lower* bounds on the length of the optimal solution -- so it won't work directly, but ...

Comment: ... you can adapt it into something that gives upper bounds by adding any upper bound on the remaining parts of the sequences.  For example, suppose string #1 has length 100 and string #2 has length 200, and you are at a search node where you have already decided that the first 10 characters of sequence #1 and the first 15 characters of sequence #2 have a common subsequence of length 5: you could get an *upper* bound on the best possible CS length achievable with the remaining 90 characters from S #1 and the remaining 185 characters of S #2 by counting character frequencies, taking the ...

Comment: ... minimum between the 2 sequences for each character, and adding these minimums.  This upper bound can be added to the CS of length 5 that you have already decided.

Comment: @j_random_hacker  Thank you, I somewhat got what you are saying about the bound but it is not very clear to me. If possible could you please provide a pseudo code for solving the problem.